# How to update a Set Filter to ag-grid v21?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have custom BaseSetFilter that extends SetFilter.  It works with ag-grid v20.2.0 and does not even build with ag-grid v21.0.1. There are notes about breaking changes (see AG-2946 in [ag-grid v21.0.0 changelog](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=21.0.0)) and to create [custom floating filters](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filter-component/) after the Filter Refactor, but no guidance on how to change an existing filter to work with the new version.

**What must change to upgrade a custom filter from ag-grid v20 to ag-grid v21? 
So many breaking changes are not documented.**

Here's what I did so far ... none of these were in the release notes or the documentation:

- renamed `BaseFilter` to `SimpleFilter` to access the static operators.
- redeclared `GridCell`, `GridCellDef`, and `GridRow` which were deleted from ag-grid.
- renamed property `filterParams` to `providedFilterParams`, but that is private so it did not help.
- renamed method `customInit` to `init`.
- renamed method `serialize` to `getModelFromUi`.
- removed generic types after `IFloatingFilter` and `IFloatingFilterParams`.
- commented out code to satisfy `ng serve`.

Typescript (in VS Code and `ng serve`) reports errors that indicate the filter-related interfaces and classes have changed in breaking ways, e.g.:

- Property 'valueModel' is private and only accessible within class 'SetFilter'.
- Property 'providedFilterParams' is private and only accessible within class 'ProvidedFilter'.
- Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'BaseSetFilter'.
- Property 'onFloatingFilterChanged' does not exist on type 'IFilterComp'.
- Property 'initialiseFilterBodyUi' is private in type 'SetFilter' but not in type 'BaseSetFilter'.

Comment: The filter-specific default translations are private in SimpleFilter (which inherits from ProvidedFilter), but SetFilter (which inherits from ProvidedFilter) cannot see them. How should a custom SetFilter translate the filter type codes, e.g. "contains", "notContains", "endsWith"?